# List of empty SVG elements

Tags: html, svg, web

There is a [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) of the empty HTML elements. Does something similar exist for empty SVG elements?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#svg-mathml

Comment: Pretty much all elements can accept a <title>, <desc> or <animate> child